# Flowgear local mysql server connectivity problem using droppoint

Tags: integration, flowgear

I am trying to connect to my local mysql server instance via dropoint. I am getting an error saying that Test Failed: MySQL Query (MySqlQuery 3.0.1.1): DropPoint Invoke Error while validating request: The Node is not permitted to execute because its input Properties are not permitted. I enabled whitelisting option in flowgear console. How can I resolve this error?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest that you disable your tests. When we consider how a `Connection` is set up in Flowgear, we know that you have to specify your SQL Server as well as the DB the connection, so this means that the connection through the DropPoint cannot connect to other servers or databases until a new `Connection` is set up with other Server details.

When doing `Connection` tests on a DropPoint, you would not be able to access Properties like Server name. You would only be able to use the Property names in the left pane in the `Property` column of the DropPoint Whitelisting screen (`Connection` and `Query`).